# find nearest restaurant from current location?

Tags: c#, android, sql-server, xamarin

i have sql server 2012 database. i have table restaurant master. in that table i am storing restaurant latitude and longitude. now what i want to do is when user search for restaurant he can sort using distance. so i am getting user current location (lat,long) but confused with sql query how to perform calculation?

here is my table

```
RestLatitude    RestLongitude    Restid
21.1784472        72.9627693        1
21.5724180        72.9648222        2
```

My Expected Output Wold like, based on current user location, want to display nearest restaurant first.

Comment: Would the user search includes radius? or distance from the user location?

Comment: are you fetching restaurant lat/lng values from google's direction api??

Comment: @icaneatclouds No Radius no distance.! only nearest one first and farest at last no matter nearest one is 100 mile away.

Comment: @sumit no i am using GoogleLocationService (dll C# Code)

Answer (score 0):

there is a easy hack for this

first cast the latitude and longitude into numeric

then try something like

```
select resturent,cast(restLatitude as numeric(18,10))-cast(@userLatitude as numeric(18,10)) as Distance from table order by Distance asc
```

add the longitude also

so logically the lowest value will be the closest place ...

P.S try something like this its not the accurate one but a thought how u could do it

Comment: select cast(RestaurantLatitude as numeric(18,10))-cast(@userlat as numeric(18,10))-CAST(RestaurantLongitude as numeric(18,10))-CAST(@uselong as numeric(18,10)) as Distance from table order by Distance asc    

like this?

Comment: yep something like hat but you dont need to minus everything  
select cast(RestaurantLatitude as numeric(18,10))-cast(@userlat as numeric(18,10))as Latitude ,CAST(RestaurantLongitude as numeric(18,10))-CAST(@uselong as numeric(18,10) asLngitude from table order by Distance asc